# Is it possible to embed AWS Cloudwatch dashboards in a webpage for internal company use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I really like the AWS Cloudwatch dashboard feature, but it would be far more useful if I could increase visibility to it to let others in our company who might not know AWS. Is there any way of displaying it outside of the AWS website?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

kraught's answer is actually the correct one and should not be downvoted. CloudWatch Dasboards now literally have a share option. You can share your dashboards a) publicly, b) via username/password or c) SSO. Either way you set this up, you eventually get a shareable link that's accessible outside of the AWS console and you can easily embed this in your website.

Comment: I would not consider it public if you need a username and password.

Comment: Those are 3 different options. 1) public access 2) username/password access 3) SSO access.

Answer (score 1):

AWS just released [CW dashboard sharing](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/amazon-cloudwatch-dashboards-supports-sharing/?sc_channel=em&sc_campaign=Launch_mult_OT_awsroadmapemail_20200910&sc_medium=em_whats_new&sc_content=launch_ot_ot&sc_country=mult&sc_geo=mult&sc_category=mult&sc_outcome=launch).  This allows it to be exported but at this time I have not found a widget that would allow them to be displayed in our Confluence pages.  If anyone has ideas it would be really appreciated.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.